How to show an existing Umbraco Member field on a Member record in the CMS
The cmsMember record contains a field called "emailConfirmedDate" but it doesn't show on a Member record when viewing in the CMS.
Can I add it - just as a label - I just want to be able to view it, not edit it.
Umbraco 13
